# Retrieve the first item of an array in a sub-document without getting other sub-documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

In MongoDB - how do you retrieve only the first item of an array which is in a property?

I have a nested document and query it with `$text` (but that doesn't matter, normal queries don't work either)

The structure of my document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("...."),
    "propA": {
        "prop1": [
            { ... }, // this is what I want to see
            { ... },
            ...
        ],
        "prop2": { ... },
        "prop3": { ... },
        ...
    },
    "propB": {
        "prop1": { ... }, // +this, but that's not a problem
        "prop2": { ... },
        "prop3": { ... },
        ...
    },
    "propC": { ... },
    ...
}
```

when I run

```
collection.find({}, { "propA.prop1": 1, "propB.prop2": 1 });
```

I get the full array at `propA.prop1`. When I run instead

```
collection.find({}, { "propA.prop1": {$slice: 1}, "propB.prop2": 1 });
```

I get only the first item of `propA.prop1` but I get also all the other items inside `propA` (like `propA.prop2`, `propA.prop3`, ...)

I'd want to somehow combine the two queries, but couldn't figure out how (except after retrieving in code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this by including a second, non-existent field of `propA` in your projection:

```js
collection.find({}, { 
    "propA.prop1": {$slice: 1},
    "propA.nonExistentField": 1,
    "propB.prop2": 1
});
```

A bit odd, but it works.

Comment: This seems like a very terrible hack for me, but it works - I hope mongodb won't "fix" it any time soon

Comment: @peter Agreed, I suggest holding your nose while you type it.